# Home button, quick settings, lock screen won't work on Moto G 2015

Tags: nexus-5, motorola-moto-g, 6.0-marshmallow, bugs, motorola-moto-g3

We have a 2015 Moto G that's less than 2 months old, and already exhibiting all the symptoms shown in [this forum thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-6-0-marshmallow/600742-nexus-5-marshmallow-home-button-not-working-many-more-problems.html):

- Home button doesn't work when in an app, but does work in application switcher (only)
- Notification curtain pulls down with no notifications, even when I should have some.  Can't pull down again to get quick settings, or tap on user icon to swtich
- I can set up screen lock but it doesn't actually work.  It never times out to lock, and isn't locked after a reboot (not using Smart Lock)

These symptoms don't seem like they should be connected but it's the exact same set as that other thread -- which is about a totally different phone!  What on earth is going on here?  Is there any way to fix it without a full factory wipe/reset?

Comment: Just to follow up, we did do the factory reset eventually, and the symptoms went away.  I later read that this may have been a symptom of a flaky microSD card installed in "app mode" (not "storage mode").  We have since bought a replacement (faster!) card, formatted in app mode, and the problem has not recurred.